# What is the underlying structure of an std::map?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, hashmap

Somebody told me yesterday that the underlying structure of an ordered map is a binary search tree. This does not make sense to me since you cannot have O(1) retrieval if that were the case. Can anyone explain?

Also, if one were to implement a hash table in C++ without using the stdlib, what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: where did you learn that retrieval is O(1)? Firstly read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), secondly they are typically implemented as [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), thirdly your other question is too broad

Comment: Also try to limit yourself to one question per question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The underlying data structure is implementation-defined. It is most commonly implemented as a Red-Black tree which is a self-balancing binary search tree. The time complexity for getting an element is O(logn) (see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at))
2. I would just read the implementation of `std::unordered_map` as a starting point. I assume this is learning activity so reading and understanding working STL implementation would be a good exercise. If it's not an exercise then use `std::unordered_map`

Answer (score 3):

std::map lookup time is not O(1) its O(log(n)).

std::unordered_map has a lookup time of O(1) amortized.

std::unordered_map and std::unordered_set are hashtables.

Answer (score 0):

std::map uses Red-Black tree as it gets a reasonable trade-off between the complexity of node insertion/deletion and searching.

Comment: That's true of current implementations, but it isn't required by the standard.  (Nobody currently knows another data structure that can meet the requirements - but one might be discovered tomorrow.)